# ComboBox coding to obtain data from a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Excel for Mac 2011, Virtual Basic Editor.
I'm setting up a new form.  I've given the labels names as well as the text boxes.  I've included 4 dropdown boxes (combo boxes) that I want to pull data from the Excel sheet that store the data.  Example, the first dropdown combobox is for selecting a State Abbreviation Code such as AL for Alabama or FL for Florida.  I've created the State Sheet, in column A I added all of the State Abbreviations.  The Mac version does not allow for the RowSource.
All advice welcomed.

Here's the alternate code I wrote that is giving me Run-Time Error '9' Subscript out of Range

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  cboState1.List = Worksheets("wsState").Range("A2:A52").Value

End Sub
```

Run-Time Error '9' Subscript out of Range

Comment: Recheck the Combobox Name, Sheet Name. Your codes looks correct to me.

Comment: Sorry, there are multiple drop-down boxes... this is the one the correlates to my example:   cboState1.List = Worksheets("wsState").Range("A2:A52").Value